# check if point is on a plane (using Heron formula ?)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, analytic-geometry, surfaces

**Is this true that if any of parameters a, b, c, d is equal to sum of three others then 4 points are on same plane?**

---

I am given 4 points in 3 dimensional space. Is this correct to state that all 4 points belong to some, one and the same plane if and only if a [content](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath664/kmath664.htm)

[image]

of a [tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) with vertices being these points is 0 (zero) ?

### Heron-type formula for the volume of a tetrahedron is

[image]

[image]

where **U, V, W, u, v, w** are lengths of edges of the tetrahedron (first three form a triangle; **u** opposite to **U** and so on). This is derived from the [Cayley–Menger determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry#Cayley.E2.80.93Menger_determinants).

So one can test therefore if Volume = 0, thus if any of parameters **a**, **b**, **c**, **d** is equal to sum of three others?

Comment: why did someone vote to close it? What is unclear?

Comment: I don't see any vote to close. But you should convert this to $\LaTeX$.

Comment: It may be easier to calculate the areas of the four faces of the tetrahedron and check whether one is the sum of the other three.

Comment: @Ragnar but is this true that if  any of parameters a, b, c, d is equal to sum of three others, then 4 points are on same plane?

Comment: @lizusek, yes, the four points are in a plane **if and only if** one on the areas of the four triangles you can make has an area equal to the sum of the other three.

Comment: @Ragnar but is this true that if any of parameters a, b, c, d is equal to sum of three others, then 4 points are on same plane? I am asking if I can test for this condition. I am given distances of vertices.

Comment: @lizusek, you don't need the $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ that you describe above. Just calculate the areas of the triangles using Herons formula for triangles.

Comment: @Ragnar thank you very much, it is of course the right idea, I will use it, but I would really like also to know if formula for Volume = 0 is correct too

Comment: @lizusek, if the volume you get using the above formula are nonnegative (which they are, because of the square roots and lengths), that should work too.

Comment: @Ragnar thank you very much, you can post this as an answer, I will accept this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the lengths of the edges of the tetrahedron are given, you can indeed calculate the volume of the tetrahedron (assuming the formula you gave is correct) and check whether or not is equals $0$. It may be easier however to just calculate the areas of the four faces of the tetrahedron (using Herons formula) and check whether one area equals the sum of the other three.

Comment: the [formula was found on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron). I am not sure of course of its precision - but the accuracy of the idea is important at the moment

Comment: @lizusek, precision shouldn't be a problem, unless you want a really high precision (near machine-precision).

Comment: this is what I said, precision of this formula (the correctness) is not important for me at the moment, I am interested in the correctness of the idea

Answer (score 0):

Four points, 
$(x_0\mid y_0\mid z_0)$, $(x_1\mid y_1\mid z_1)$, $(x_2\mid y_2\mid z_2)$ and $(x_3\mid y_3\mid z_3)$, are coplanar if the determinant 
$\begin{vmatrix}
x_0&y_0&z_0&1\\
x_1&y_1&z_1&1\\
x_2&y_2&z_2&1\\
x_3&y_3&z_3&1\\ 
\end{vmatrix}$ vanishes.

Comment: this is not an answer to my question. I know this already. Can you tell if the idea of testing a,b,c,d parameters in my formula (as described in question) is correct based on this?

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to checking whether one point is a linear combination of the other three points.